# How can I calculate total price with piece in GridView in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview

I want to find the total price in Gridview but when I do this I have to keep track of the piece. For example If I bought 4 shoes, and And the price of 1 shoes is 20. I should 20*4 for total price. How can I do that in GridView

```
decimal price = 0;
int piece = 0;
decimal totalPrice = 0;
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        price += Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "price"));
        piece += Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "piece"));
        totalPrice = price * piece;
    }
    else if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "Total Price:";
        e.Row.Cells[2].Text = totalPrice.ToString("c");
        e.Row.Cells[1].HorizontalAlign = e.Row.Cells[2].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
        e.Row.Font.Bold = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: In RowDataBound event of GridView you can fetch price and quantity from your datasource and multiply it and use it. Please include the code part in your question and exactly what problem you are facing.

Comment: I included my code behind. Can you check please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this to show the total in footer. I am omitting exception handling for simplicity here.

```
decimal price = 0;
int piece = 0;
decimal totalPrice = 0;
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // This will multiply the price and piece and add it to final total.
        totalPrice += Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "price")) * Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "piece"));
    }
    else if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "Total Price:";
        e.Row.Cells[2].Text = totalPrice.ToString("c");
        e.Row.Cells[1].HorizontalAlign = e.Row.Cells[2].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
        e.Row.Font.Bold = true;
    }
}
```